# Width of featured questions is too small

Tags: bug, android-app

Featured questions are badly formatted

Screenshot:
[image]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: SGP771

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (1994651638)